# Find min, max and sum of non-common variables in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in Python.

```
dict_list = [ {"k1" : "abc", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3", "k4": 2},
              {"k1" : "v21", "k2": "v22", "k3": "v23", "k4": 5},
              {"k1" : "abc", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3", "k4": 10} ]
```

I need to get min/max and sum of "k4" key for common k1, k2, k3 fields. For example for the above dict_list, the output should be:

```
[
 {"k1" : "abc", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v3", "min": 2, "max": 10, "sum": 12},
 {"k1" : "v21", "k2": "v22", "k3": "v23", "min": 5, "max": 5, "sum": 5}
]
```

I'm planning to use Counter container to get the common fields.

```
counter_out = Counter((d["k1"], d["k2"], d["k3"]) for d in dict_list)
```

Then I plan to use counter_out to iterate in the original dict_list. Is there a better approach to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `Counter` is going to give you `min`, `max` and `sum`. Probably the simplest way is to create an intermediate dict with `('k1', 'k2', 'k3')` as the key and a list of values.
And then it is relatively simply to transform this back into the `dict` structure you are looking for, e.g:

```
In [1]:
from collections import defaultdict
t = defaultdict(list)
for d in dict_list:
    t[tuple(d[k] for k in ['k1', 'k2', 'k3'])].append(d['k4'])

[{'k1':k[0], 'k2':k[1], 'k3':k[2], 'min':min(v), 'max':max(v), 'sum':sum(v)} 
 for k, v in t.items()]

Out[1]:
[{'k1': 'abc', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3', 'max': 10, 'min': 2, 'sum': 12},
 {'k1': 'v21', 'k2': 'v22', 'k3': 'v23', 'max': 5, 'min': 5, 'sum': 5}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped.